# PDF to HTML API that supports named pages

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am looking for a Web Service (API) for HTML to PDF conversion that supports the @page directive and named pages. I need to display different headers and footers on different pages. I did quite a lot of research, but so far the only API that supports I found is DocRaptor (uses PDF-specific engine Prince). Does maybe anybody know of some other APIs that support this? Should also support PHP.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks and regards, Grega

Answer (score -1):

I think this will answer your questions

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

[HTML to PDF](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Comment: Thank you for your anwser @Fel, but this is not what I am looking form (I also use Datatables). I do not want to export table data to PDFs from table data, I need to create custom PDFs with the option to display different headers and footers.

Comment: tell me if that was helpful to  you

Comment: Unfortunately this was not helpful to me, as I wrote I am looking for a Web Service (API) not a library. Right know I am using https://github.com/mpdf, but I need to outsource PDF creation.